# Как копировать файлы в fasm?

Tags: fasm, копирование

Как мне, например, файл 'E:\text.txt' скопировать в папку 'E:\files'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если папки `E:\Files` не существует, то функция `CopyFile()` вернёт ошибку. Тогда нужно сначала создать папку через `CreateFile()` и только потом в неё копировать.

```
format pe gui
include 'win32ax.inc'
;//----------
.data
oldFile   db   'D:\cpuz.txt',0
newFile   db   'D:\files\cpuz.txt',0
;//----------
.code
start:   invoke  CopyFile,oldFile,newFile,0
         or      eax,eax
         jne     @ok
         invoke  MessageBox,0,<'ERROR! Нет папки D:\Files',0>,<'Copy',0>,0
         jmp     @f
@ok:     invoke  MessageBox,0,<'OK! Файл скопирован.',0>,<'Copy',0>,0
@@:      invoke  ExitProcess,0
;//------------
.end start
```

Comment: Не получается скомпилировать. Пишет value out of range

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: `Пишет value out of range` - вот полный исходник.